# ABContact setImage, thumbnail bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, contacts, addressbook

I have setup addressbook contact's images using a code,
it works well and the image is there when I browse the Addressbook,

But when a call comes, it only shows a thumbnail? I want to show the full image instead the thumbnail? Is it a bug?

```
        NSData *dataRef = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(entry.recIcon,1.0);     
        CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);       
        ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &error);        
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
        BOOL ret = ABPersonSetImageData(person, cfdata, &error);
        if (ret) {
            ret = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Could not write the image to the person");
        }
        CFRelease(cfdata);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer,

Iphone sdk saves the images type as thumbnail automatically if the image replaced is not big enough, if it is big enough it shows the full image when a call comes. there's nothing wrong with the code.